# Sorting non-negative integers in linear time using Numba breaks

Tags: python, sorting, numba

I am trying to sort an array/list of non-negative integers in linear time. We also only keep the unique elements. Here is an example,

```
Sort: [7, 7, 0, 3, 2, 1, 9, 1]

7: 10000000
7: 10000000
0: 10000001
3: 10001001
2: 10001101
1: 10001111
9: 1010001111
1: 1010001111

1010001111: []
101000111: [0]
10100011: [0, 1]
1010001: [0, 1, 2]
101000: [0, 1, 2, 3]
10100: [0, 1, 2, 3]
1010: [0, 1, 2, 3]
101: [0, 1, 2, 3]
10: [0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
: [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9]
```

Essentially, I am implementing `np.unique([7, 7, 0, 3, 2, 1, 9, 1])` in linear time. Here is my Python,

```py
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
from numba import njit

# @njit
def count(ls):
    ret = []
    m = 0
    for x in ls:
        m = m | (1 << int(x))
    i = 0
    while m > 0:
        if (m & 1):
            ret.append(i)
        m = m >> 1
        i += 1
    return ret

RNG = np.random.default_rng(0)

x = RNG.integers(2**16, size=2**17)
start = perf_counter()
y1 = np.unique(x)
print(perf_counter() - start)
start = perf_counter()
y2 = count(x)
print(perf_counter() - start)
print((y1 == y2).all())
```

My "O(n)" sort did not beat Numpy's unique function.  I expected that since Python is slower than C (which is where `np.unique` is implemented I am guessing). To remedy this, I tried using Numba's JIT decorator. But--if I uncomment the decorator, somehow the function breaks and returns an empty list. It works without the decorator.

Can someone please point out my oversight?

Comment: "Here is an example" - this doesn't even remotely explain the algorithm you want to use. Please try using complete English sentences to describe how the code should work.

Comment: Karl--it is a secret kept too well for me to just give it away. In all seriousness, all linear time sorting algorithms work on the same idea. The example was just me confirming for the reader that I, in-fact, am not mistaken on the correctness of the algorithm. The mistake, as pointed out by the selected answer was due to a type constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses arbitrary-precision integers to represent all integers. This is often useful, but has the disadvantage of being slow. To make this faster, Numba uses 64 bit signed integers.

One of the consequences of this is that 1 << 63 is a negative number in Numba.

The following test program will show this.

```
from numba import njit


@njit
def shift(amount):
    return 1 << amount


for i in range(66):
    print(i, hex(shift(i)))
```

Then, `while m > 0:` exits immediately. This is why the numba version gives an empty list, and also why this can't work correctly in general if you have more than 64 numbers.

Comment: Does Numba have a type to accommodate arbitrary-precision integers?

Comment: @scribe I don't think so: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5005#issuecomment-569309990 You could try making an array of booleans in numpy. That would only cost you N bytes, where N is the largest integer in your data.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid that since that requires 8 times the memory. Thank you though, your answer at least cleared what was wrong.